# nginx port specific sub domain

Tags: nginx

I have the following which works fine.

```
server {
    listen 8080;
    server_name sub.example.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://10.0.1.88:8080/;
    }
}

server {
    listen 80 default_server;

    root /var/www/html;

    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name example.com;
    #server_name _;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
}
```

1. http://sub.example.com:8080 = expected result
2. http://example.com = expected result
3. http://example.com:8080 = unexpected result = same as first

The third shows exactly the same as the first where I expected it to fail?

What I would like to happen is either -

a. redirect back to port 80

```
OR
```

b. return a 404

This has been doing my head in for hours :(

Appreciate the help.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html) but pay particular attention to the concept of a *default server*.

Both of the `server` blocks in your question are default servers. One implicitly and one explicitly. Any request received on port 8080 (irrespective of host name) will be handled by the first server block. Likewise for the second block and port 80.

If you want to enforce your `server_name` directive, you will need to create a new *catch all* `server` block with a `listen 8080 default_server;` directive, and place your required actions in there.

For example:

```
server {
    listen 8080 default_server;
    return 301 http://example.com/;
}
```

Comment: thanks for that @richard was a real help... however it did introduce a problem...

now when use http://sub.example.com/ it shows the http://example.com

does that mean i need to create another server block to handle this case?

This would get rather long if you had many sub domains or am I missing something...

Comment: It has nothing to do with sub domains. You have an implicit or explicit default server for every port you listen on. In a conventional configuration, all of your sites would use port 80 for `http`, which means only one server block is the catch all.